# fast/efficient way to run a query in Access based on datatable rows?

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, datatable

I have a datatable that may have 1000 or so rows in it. I need to go thru the datatable row by row, get the value of a column, run a query (Access 2007 DB) and update the datatable with the result. Here's what I have so far, which works:

```
String FilePath = "c:\\MyDB.accdb";

string QueryString = "SELECT MDDB.NDC, MDDB.NDC_DESC "
    + "FROM MDDB_MASTER AS MDDB WHERE MDDB.NDC = @NDC";

OleDbConnection strAccessConn = new OleDbConnection(string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + FilePath));
strAccessConn.Open();
OleDbDataReader reader = null;

int rowcount = InputTable.Rows.Count; //InputTable is the datatable
int count = 0;

while (count < rowcount)
{
    string NDC = InputTable.Rows[count]["NDC"].ToString(); 
    //NDC is a column in InputTable                      

    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(QueryString, strAccessConn);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@NDC", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = NDC;

    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        //update the NDCDESC column with the query result
        //the query should only return 1 line
        dataSet1.Tables["InputTable"].Rows[count]["NDCDESC"] = reader.GetValue(1).ToString();
    }

    dataGridView1.Refresh();
    count++;
}
strAccessConn.Close();
```

However this seems very inefficient since the query needs to run one time for each row in the datatable. Is there a better way?

Comment: wondering what if you try to do all of that in sproc?

Comment: what version of Access?

Comment: @EkoostikMartin - Access 2007

Comment: is the MDDB_MASTER table very large? you could copy the entire table by running the query without a WHERE clause and then search a .NET DataTable object using LINQ

Comment: @nicholas - MDDB_MASTER is 225,000 rows, and 75 columns so it's fairly large.

Comment: Where's `InputTable` coming from? Something outside of Access? That changes the problem a bit. But I wonder if you can roll through all of InputTable and create a text file of `{ key, update_value }` and then import it back into the original source of `InputTable` for a join later. Is that crazy?

Comment: @catfood - InputTable is populated from an Excel spreadsheet. I have some simple code that does `SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]` and fills InputTable

Comment: it may be possible to create a query in the access database then that selects from the Excel spreadsheet.. then you could perform a JOIN query on the Access table and Excel spreadsheet, and then the .NET application would only have to perform one OleDB operation

Comment: Oh, in *that* case, why not just skip `InputTable` and roll through the Excel sheet using the Excel COM object?

Also, regardless, definitely put the creation of the `OleDbCommand` outside the big loop. You don't need to instantiate it and create its parameter object every time though. Simply change the value of the parameter and execute as needed.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, I copied MDDB_MASTER to a datatable and it only took a few minutes. Granted, the database is stored locally on my machine. The users will be accessing a copy on the network.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missed the part about InputTable coming from Excel.

For better speed, instead of executing the query in Access over and over, you can get all rows from MDDB_MASTER into a datatable in one select statement:

```
SELECT MDDB.NDC, MDDB.NDC_DESC FROM MDDB_MASTER
```

And then use the [DataTable.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50.aspx) method to filter the right row.

```
mddb_master.Select("NDC = '" + NDC +'")
```

This will be done in memory and should be much faster than all the round trips you have now. Especially over the network these round trips are expensive. 225k rows should be only a few MB (roughly a JPEG image) so that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: thank you gjvdkamp .. I think pulling the data from MDDB_MASTER to into a temp datatable is the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

You're thinking of an [update query](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/update-data-by-using-a-query-HA010076527.aspx#BM5). You don't actually have to go over every row one by one. SQL is a [set based language](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/the-road-to-professional-database-development-set-based-thinking/), so you only have to write a single statement that it should do for all rows.

Do this:

1) Create > Query Design

2) Close the dialog that selects tables

3) Make sure you're in sql mode (top left corner)

4) Paste this:

```
UPDATE INPUTTABLE 
INNER JOIN MDDB_MASTER ON INPUTTABLE.NDC = MDDB_MASTER.NDC 
SET INPUTTABLE.NDCDESC = [MDDB_MASTER].[NDC_DESC];
```

5) Switch to design mode to see what happens. You may have to correct Input table, I couldn't find it's name. I'm assuming they;re both in the same database.

You'll see the query type is now an update query.

You can run this text through `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(sql)` and the whole thing should run very quickly. If it doesn't you'll need an index on one of the tables;

THis works by joining the two table on NDC and then copying the NDC_DESC over from MDDB_MASTER to the inputtable.

Comment: Interesting! I will give it a try. Thank you!!

Comment: Is InputTable even in Access? According to OP comments, it is loaded from an Excel spreadsheet.

Comment: Ok missed that part about Excel, you may have to suck it up into a temp table in access, do this and then put it back to excel.

Comment: I could copy the Excel file "InputTable" to a temp table in Access, but I think I'm going to copy MDDB_MASTER into a temp datatable instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the "IN" clause to build a bigger query such as:

```
string QueryString = "SELECT MDDB.NDC, MDDB.NDC_DESC "
    + "FROM MDDB_MASTER AS MDDB WHERE MDDB.NDC IN (";

int rowcount = InputTable.Rows.Count; //InputTable is the datatable
int count = 0;

while (count < rowcount)
{
    string NDC = InputTable.Rows[count]["NDC"].ToString(); 
    QueryString += (count == 0 ? "" : ",") + "'" + NDC + "'";
}
QueryString += ")";
```

You can optimize that with StringBuilders since that could be a lot of strings but that's a job for you. :)

Then in a single query, you would get all the NDC descriptions you need and avoid performing 1000 queries. You would then roll through the reader, find values in the InputTable, and update them. Of course, in this case, you're looping through the InputTable multiple times but it might be a better option. Especially if yor InputTable could hold duplicate NDC values.

Also, note that you have a OleDbDataReader leak in your code. You keep reassigning the reader reference to a new instance of a reader before disposing of the old reader. Same with commands. You keep instantiating a new command but are not disposing of it properly.